# How to iterate through pixels in clockwise direction rather usual row column scanning in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

Project is to find boundary of an image and the given idea is to find the bigger difference of pixel values between clockwise pixel locations zeroing in on the center of the image thereby finding the boundary pixel locations. Any way we can iterate through pixels in clockwise direction ?

The usual row column scan doesn't work for finding pixel difference along boundary of the image.

```
for y in 0..<rgbaImage.height {
  for x in 0..<rgbaImage.width {
    let index = x * rgbaImage.height + y

    var pixel = rgbaImage.pixels[index]
    print("\((Int32(pixel.red) + Int32(pixel.green) + Int32(pixel.blue)) / 3)", terminator:" ")
```

Comment: Clockwise as in a circle or a rectangle? Do you want to spiral in from the outside?

Comment: I want to spiral in from outside. So either method would do, circle or rectangle.

Comment: Could we achieve the idea of iteration in a spiral manner towards the center ? Any way we could achieve that ?

Comment: It will take quite a bit of work. I'd make a function to provide a horizontal and vertical strip of values given a starting point and an ending point in that row or column. Then another function that checks the array of values. Iterate by increasing your start values and decreasing your end values, creating top, right, bottom, and left arrays and then check them. Stop when your values pass each other, making sure that you don't skip over the last strip.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it gave lot of thinking to iterate spirally. So I have ran loops horizontal and vertical separately to find bigger difference in pixel values along boundary, hoping this would give me the same pixel coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example of looping in a spiral to build an n x n array. You can use the same approach to loop through an image.

Paste this into a playground to test:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

var spiral = [[Int]](count: 5, repeatedValue: [Int](count: 5, repeatedValue: 0))

var n:Int = 5

var value:Int = 0
var minCol:Int = 0
var maxCol:Int = n-1
var minRow:Int = 0
var maxRow:Int = n-1

while value != n*n {
    for var i = minCol; i <= maxCol; i += 1 {
        spiral[minRow][i] = value;
        value += 1;
    }

    for var i = minRow+1; i <= maxRow; i += 1 {
        spiral[i][maxCol] = value;
        value += 1;
    }

    for var i = maxCol-1; i >= minCol; i-- {
        spiral[maxRow][i] = value;
        value += 1;
    }

    for var i = maxRow-1; i >= minRow+1; i-- {
        spiral[i][minCol] = value;
        value += 1;
    }

    minCol += 1;
    minRow += 1;
    maxCol -= 1;
    maxRow -= 1;
}

//loop through the array we just built
for var x = 0; x < n; x += 1 {
    for var y = 0; y < n; y += 1 {
        print(spiral[x][y],terminator: "\t")
    }
    print();
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
0   1   2   3   4   
15  16  17  18  5   
14  23  24  19  6   
13  22  21  20  7   
12  11  10  9   8
```